How do I remove the extra "Shared from WhatsApp" text/footer in a caption when sharing an image or file from WhatsApp?
I'm using a Google Pixel 8 Pro with Android 14 and WhatsApp v2.24.16.76. After the last app update, when I share anything from WhatsApp to another app (such as Signal, Gmail, Google Messages, etc.), WhatsApp adds the caption:

Shared from WhatsApp
https://whatsapp.com/dl/source=sfw

I can manually delete this text every time I share something, but is there a setting to stop WhatsApp from adding this text every time? I am located in the United States (adding in response to comments).

Related on Reddit (no responses yet): "Shared from WhatsApp" added to messages when forwarding, WhatsApp adding footer to shared messages. I tried reproducing this issue, but couldn't. I'm starting to think this might be country-dependent, perhaps related to some laws I don't know.

Agree with @AndrewT. I don't see that in2.24.17.76, which is a later version than you quoted

@AndrewT. Thank you. I'm located in the United States, so I added that to the question. Very strange.

@beeshyams Thank you. I'm in the United States. Strange!

Hmm, if you're in the United States, now I doubt if it's related to the country, since almost no one and no news cover about it...

Maybe just update to the latest version, it could have been a bug that came in with your speciifc version

@beeshyams I've since updated to 2.24.17.79 and it's still there. Very strange indeed.

The only variable I can think of now is that it may be a carrier related issue, unlikely but a possibility?

I'll look into that. I have Mint Mobile which is part of T Mobile, but on an unlocked phone. A phone that was never locked to a carrier.

I've updated twice now, but I still get that annoying message Shared from WhatsApp ...
